# Custom xaml layout using RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I am new in UWP and I get some misunderstanding grid `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` as is mentioned in [oficial doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/layout/layout-panels). I have to make a custom list element, something like this:
[image]

but I can't handle it. In fact the main problem is how to set fill_parent property for a child view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method like it's indicated in your mentioned [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/layout/layout-panels). As is described in your img the last element it's in the middle vertically, so this layout will be:
[image]

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition
            Height="20" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="44" />
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="10" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle
        Fill="Red"
        Grid.RowSpan="2" 
        Grid.Column="0"/>

    <Rectangle
        Fill="Green"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1" />

    <Rectangle
        Fill="Yellow"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1" />

    <Grid
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Grid.Column="2">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition
                Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle
            Fill="Gray"
            Grid.Row="1"/>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

For simplicity and clarity I was using `Rectangle`

Answer (score 0):

Filling the space can be done with

```
width="*"
```

And the small complexity in your layout could be handled with **nested grid** system.
Here is the beginning, not the complete solution for your layout.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="44"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="44"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```